# The use of italics/citation marks for metalanguage

Tags: quotation-marks, italics

I've been taught that when words are used metalinguistically, they should be marked either with italics or with double quotation marks. Examples:

1. *Dog* is a noun.
2. *Verlan* is the name of a kind of French slang, in which you change the order of syllables.

These examples are pretty straightforward, I think. However, in the following examples,things are not as clear (or at least not to me):

3. The kids named their dog *Wierdo*
4. In the spring, we will launch our new online course *investigative journalism*
5. We are all members of the group *laudable loonies*

In these examples, is it correct to use italics (or, alternatively, double citation marks) the way I have? If it is, would it also be correct ***not*** to use them (so it's optional)?